# Django: How do I get multiple values from checkboxes in dataTable

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

In HTML, every form field needs a name attribute in order to be submitted to the server. But I used dataTable to display all data and pagination. The list checkbox just get the data of the current page not get data of next page or previous page. How can I get all the values of checkbox?

in the template

```
<input type="checkbox" name="orderId" value="{{ order_id }}" checked>
```

and in the view:

```
order_list = request.POST.getlist('orderId')
```

Comment: Make sure that 'order_list' is of type 'list'. Also you should check you are using single form for all 'checkbox' inputs or multiple forms, each for your current page. Here all 'checkbox' input fields should be included in single form for desired output.

Comment: yes, I sure only single form. I think reason in pagination of dataTable. Ex: If in my table have 2 page, current page is number 1 and I submit form then the `order_list ` just receive the values of checkbox in page number 1 and don't have any values of page number 2

Comment: You are right, when you are navigating through the pages, in the body of table it only contains rows of current page and because of this, form also contains only input fields of current page. If you know Jquery or Javascript, I can suggest you another method which will resolve your issue for sure.

Comment: so you mean we'll using ajax to send all values of checkbox to server. Is that right?

Comment: No, not that way. You can use a hidden input field(type hidden) containing the  string (comma separated value), which can later be received on server side as string and further it's splited using split method which will result in desired list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125225/discussion-between-prashant-srivastava-and-trent-fernandez).

Comment: If suggested method will work for you, please mention in comment.

Comment: It working. Thank you so much!

Comment: Since its working, i'm going to post it as answer, please mark it as correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hidden input field(type hidden) containing the string (comma separated value), which can later be received on server side as string and further it's splited using split method which will result in desired list

```
   <form> 
      <input id="result" type="hidden" name="result"> 
      <!--your data table goes here--> 
   </form> 

  <script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
     var resultarray=[]; 
     $('form input:checkbox').on('change', function(){ 

      var orderValue=$(this).val();

     // if string already available then remove(uncheck operation) 
     if(resultarray.indexOf(orderValue)!=-1) 
     { 
        resultarray.splice(resultarray.indexOf(orderValue), 1);
      } 
     else 
     { 
      //if sting is not available then add(check operation) 
      resultarray.push(orderValue);
     } 

   var text=""; 
   for(x in resultarray) 
   { 
     text+=x+",";
     //you may add an extra condition for not adding comma at last element
   }
   $("#result").val(text);
  }); 
});
```